# opencv 3.0 installation with qt for visual studio 2012

Tags: qt, opencv, visual-studio-2012, opencv3.0

Firstly I apologize you for my query because the same thing was already explained briefly in Youtube and the opencv forum for an older version. I followed up the steps but some of the download links was not available and some are not working.

So please can anybody help me to install opencv with QT support in widows7 to use with Visual studio 2012 express in step by step process and the latest download links....
 Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution from this Youtube video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30VTi_Y6tYY

In this video it was shown for opencv 2.4.11 and qt 5.4.2

But the same method really works for the latest versions of opencv and QT

I shared the link here for any help to my friends...